# PowerApps form doesn't save external data to SharePoint list

Tags: powerapp

I've created custom form with PowerApps so when you click on New button in SharePoint you will see this:

[image]

This form is for SharePoint list ***Workflow*** but for column *CostCenter* I'm using external list ***Companies and Cost Centers*** where I'm filtering values based on selected *Company* (Cascading Dropdown).

I'm able to select data in those two fields correctly but when I hit the Save button in the form the value of *CostCenter* is not saved to ***Workflow*** list but everything else is.

So *Title*, *Property Manager*, *Company*, etc. except *CostCenter* is saved. I guess it's connected to that Data Source of each field but I don't know how to send those data from *CostCenter* to ***Workflow*** too.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a collection from the lookup lists data source on the onvisible or onstart property of the screen and then set this as the data source for the drop down as suggested here https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Filter-on-Sharepoint-Lookup-field-data-not-saved/td-p/122419